# How to write a driver for virtual printer

Tags: printing, virtual

I want to write a driver for virtual printer (in C++ or Java)
(As explained in [How to create a virtual printer in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019036/how-to-create-a-virtual-printer-in-windows))
I would redirect the file to a file server (again as explained in http://www.colorpilot.com/VirtualPrinterForCSharp2.html.

What are the **fundamental building blocks of a printer driver** ?

I have read about spooler and print monitor but I am not sure that these are all that I have to know!

Any guide or suggestion appreciated in advance!

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual Printer Driver for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190476/virtual-printer-driver-for-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Most print redirection requirements are fulfilled using a Port Monitor. You dont need to do a printer driver because if you do that then this is more difficult to broadbase across end-users who may want to use their printer drivers, you will need to have drivers for each printer and so on.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/ is a very good example of a redirection port monitor. Mostly written in C. Please look at the licensing agreements before you see how you can use it in your project.

There is also a sample port monitor in the Windows WDK (Windows Driver Kit) you could use a base reference.

Hope this helps. If so, please vote a +1 :)