# How to build a virtual printer?

Tags: driver, printers, virtual-printer

I'm trying to build a virtual printer.
There are already some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640287/how-to-write-a-driver-for-virtual-printer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019036/how-to-create-a-virtual-printer-in-windows).

However my demand is more specific. I just want to create a virtual printer that can be added into the system and can be accessed from any application. On clicking print command, a dialog looks like a real printer pops out and generates a PDF on printing. Then some more actions, like pushing the PDF to my server, are performed.

Do I need to dig into Windows Driver Kit? Or is there any free SDK for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this question is still relevant to you, but you'd probably want to think about something like this:

Use the WDK (Windows Driver Kit) to create a [Unidrv UI plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This will allow you to specify UI during the print (for your printer dialogue). The reason why you'd want to show UI here is because it's one of the only printer driver components that runs in the user session (the same process as the printing application). The XPS pipeline and port monitor are both session 0.

If you want to stick to MS convention, you'll do the spool file to PDF conversion in the render filter of the [XPS Filter pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463364.aspx) (this is if you're using an [XPSDrv driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). The filter pipeline is where you have the opportunity to modify the XPS spool data coming in and in the final filter, convert it to your output document type (PDF in your case).

To do post print processing, you might want to consider creating a [port monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (again with the WDK) and kicking off a new process to do the post print processing after the port monitor writes out the print output to disk.

Only problem with this approach is that you can't use port monitors in Version 4 drivers (this is the new type of driver in Windows 8). Version 3 drivers still work in Win 8, but I guess they'll be phased out eventually.

Sorry it's probably not very obvious, but as I say, it's a high level overview (and unfortunately driver development is still very complex beyond a simple print to file). Version 4 printer drivers are becoming a lot easier to develop, but unfortunately with the removal of port monitor support and other improvements, it makes it a lot harder to develop anything requiring post processing.

*[DISCLAIMER: I'm associated with the Mako SDK R&D team]*
I know you asked for a free SDK, unfortunately I don't know of anything that would be suitable, but I know our company offer a Virtual Printer Platform (SDK) which would be good for you (prints to PDF and supports post print processing). You can find more information at the [Mako SDK website](https://www.globalgraphics.com/products/mako-sdk)

Hope this helps a bit anyway. I know printer driver development can be very confusing at times!

Answer (score 2):

After reading up and doing a lot of research, with the aim to setup up something like redmon and use the printer SDK, I have completed the project using this SDK: http://www.novapdf.com/pdf-sdk.html

This solution however will work with windows only.

**[I am not affiliated with novaPDF]**

I have investigated an OSX version, however this will be a different build, you can probably set something up using this method: http://www.jms1.net/osx-pdf-services.shtml **[I have not yet tried this]**